# Continue previous page numbering (Roman/Arabic) with two independent counters?

Tags: page-numbering, counters, roman

Assumed I want to write a document with abstract, acknowledgements, three chapters, two appendices and a statutory declaration.

Hereby...

- Abstract and acknowledgement should be numbered in `Roman` format
- Chapters 1 - 3 should be numbered in `Arabic` format
- Appendices should be numbered in `Roman` format
- Statutory declaration should be numbered in `Arabic` format

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{appendix}

\newcounter{savepage}

\begin{document}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}

    \chapter{Abstract}%                     Roman numbering
    \chapter{Acknowledgements}%             Roman numbering

    \cleardoublepage
    \setcounter{savepage}{\arabic{page}}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \chapter{The first chapter}%            Arabic numbering
    \chapter{The second chapter}%           Arabic numbering
    \chapter{The third chapter}%            Arabic numbering

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}

    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{The first appendix}%       Roman numbering
        \chapter{The second appendix}%      Roman numbering
    \end{appendices}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \chapter{Statutory declaration}%        Arabic numbering

\end{document}
```

---

The MWE above is working fine with regard to numbering style. However, this approach is resetting the `page counter` of statutory declaration to page no. 1 (although it should be page no. 4).

How can I introduce a second `\setcounter` command that will continue the `Arabic` numbering for the statutory declaration?

Comment: you don't need a new counter just use `\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}` instead of `\pagenumbering` which just does that but also sets the counter to 1, which you do not need.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks a lot for your kind help! Unfortunately I do not understand where to put your code - could you maybe post a `MWE` please?

Comment: Please, check your question. The body says one thing, the example code comments say another.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh, I am sorry for that! I just recompiled the code again by myself and everything works fine - why this isn't a working MWE?

Comment: @Dave sorry I was clearly tired, I deleted that comment:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a confusing numbering scheme ...

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{appendix}

\newcounter{savepageRoman}
\newcounter{savepagearabic}

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\chapter{Abstract}%                     Roman numbering
\chapter{Acknowledgements}%             Roman numbering

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{savepageRoman}{\value{page}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{The first chapter}%            Arabic numbering
\chapter{The second chapter}%           Arabic numbering
\chapter{The third chapter}%            Arabic numbering

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{savepagearabic}{\value{page}}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{savepageRoman}}

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{The first appendix}%       Roman numbering
    \chapter{The second appendix}%      Roman numbering
\end{appendices}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{\value{savepagearabic}}

\chapter{Statutory declaration}%        Arabic numbering
\end{document}
```

---

I would suggest to use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter` and `\appendix`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\pagenumbering{Roman}% <- pagenumbers Roman instead roman
\chapter{Abstract}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{The first chapter}
\chapter{The second chapter}
\chapter{The third chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{The first appendix}
\chapter{The second appendix}

\backmatter
\chapter{Statutory declaration}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "That is a confusing numbering scheme ..." - You think this is uncommon and should better be avoided?

Comment: @dave Yes, very uncommon. These days, you don't even need one different numbering scheme as pagination isn't done by hand anymore.

Comment: Yes, I would avoid this. Maybe you can use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter` and `\appendix` to structure your document.